# WCF Behavior Extension Elements Not Recognized in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf, service, behavior

This question is related to the question posted here:

[Why isn't my custom WCF behavior extension element type being found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169342/why-isnt-my-custom-wcf-behavior-extension-element-type-being-found)

I'm using the WCF Behavior Extension with Custom Credentials demonstrated on MSDN here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730868.aspx

The only difference is that I'm using the Custom Token created from the WCF Custom Token Sample in the SDK. This involves creating a CreditCard credentials.

Having all the code in place I add the extension through the WCF Configuration GUI. I know it's working because it recognizes the type and adds the extensions to the config file.

```
      <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name="creditCardServiceCredentials" type="CreditCard.CreditCardServiceCredentialsConfigHandler, CreditCard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <add name="creditCardClientCredentials" type="CreditCard.CreditCardClientCredentialsConfigHandler, CreditCard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
```

After adding those elements I can use the WCF Configuration GUI to add the custom behaviors to the service behaviors element or the endpoint behaviors element. I don't see the properties though but it does show the type itself as it were a ServiceCredentials or ClientCredentials type.

Though, when I use the editor itself it doesn't show up in intellisense or as a recognized element.

**I'm referencing the project that contains the credit card credentials configuration handlers; so the DLL is in the service's bin\Debug directory. It's odd that it still doesn't work though :(**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to extend the visual studio xml editor with intellisense, take a look at this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2005/12/07/501466.aspx

Comment: So when you add a custom config section or in this case a behavior extension, is it correct to assume that Visual Studio will not know what to put there?