# WCF failed to update the configuration file when adding service

Tags: c#, wcf, ierrorhandler, servicebehavior

I have added a service behavior extension to the default service behavior for logging un-handled exceptions, which is working as expected.

```
<extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="UnhandledExceptions" 
        type="MyApp.WebServices.Behaviours.Extensions.UnhandledExceptionExtention, MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <UnhandledExceptions />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

However, when I try to add a new service into the project I get the following error:

> Failed to update the configuration file
>
> The type 'MyApp.WebServices.Behaviours.Extensions.UnhandledExceptionExtention, MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' registired for extention 'UnhandledExceptions ' could not be loaded. Web.config line XX

To get around this; I comment out the extension usage in the service behavior, add the service and undo the config change.

Although this is a workable solution I would rather not have to depend upon myself and other developers remembering what appears to be an unnecessary process.

Is there a way this can be fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't my custom WCF behavior extension element type being found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169342/why-isnt-my-custom-wcf-behavior-extension-element-type-being-found)